# .NET: DDD and ASMX, avoid multiple namespaces on proxy classes

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, domain-driven-design, asmx

I am new to DDD and at the moment I try to refactor a project towards a domain driven architecture. The project has a client and a server side (ASMX webservice). Now I created a class libary called "Domain" which is referenced by the client application as well as by the server.

Now I want my SOAP communication to be based on my domain model. But as you know the ASMX webservice creates some kind of proxy class library within the client as soon as a web reference is established.
This results in **having each domain entity and value object twice under different namespaces**.

1. Is it possible to use the domain model for communication directly and **avoid the generation of the ASMX proxy classes**?
2. How are DTOs used within DDD? As you know, some domain parts might not be serializable (e.g. NHibernate / IList usage) so in the past I often created simpler DTO-versions of my entity classes. **Is it a common practice to define DTO entities within the domain**?

Comment: which solution did you choose? Have you tried mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use **WCF**, you could have the service interface and DTO classes in a **shared assembly** that both the client and the server referenced.     Converting your project to use WCF may not be too hard, but there is a lot of learning to do before you get started.

A shared interface assembly is only a good ideal if you wish the client and server to be **tightly joined**, hence it does not work well unless **both side are owned by the same team**.

Often trying to use the same classes on the server and client lean to deign problem, however sharing classes when it does fit the design saves a lot of work.

(Sorry I don’t think you can used a shared assembly with asmx, it is more a concept from the remoting side of .net history)

Comment: Thank you. The server as well as the client are owned by our team. However I don't want to migrate to WCF at the moment, though this should be the right direction in the long run.

Regarding WCF: Our client software is stuck to .NET 2.0, so regarding to some blogs, I'd have to use BasicHTTPBinding. Does this binding also support the usage of a common domain library?

Comment: @mbue, you may be able to use .net remoting hosted in IIS (I have done this in the past and it works well, provided you control both ends)  I recall that "Ingo Rammer" books were very helpful in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible to use original domain model** (obtained by a reference -not a WEB reference- to the domain model) for communication with the ASMX: you must use the model exposed by asmx that is similar but not the same (i.e. List are transformed in Array).

**It's possible -and easy- create many classes** from many web-services having the **same namespace**.
Create a *.bat* file like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\wsdl.exe" /sharetypes /o:C:\code\MyProxy.cs /namespace:MyProxies http://website/FirstService.asmx http://website/SecondService.asmx  
Pause
```

Where
-`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\wsdl.exe"`  is **wsdl.exe** with relative path (it must be on your PC)
-`/sharetypes` means that you want **only 1 namespace** in the output
- `/o:C:\code\MyProxy.cs` is the ***.cs* file name** that will contain all the classes created
- `/namespace:MyProxies` is the **namespace for all the classes** created
- `http://website/FirstService.asmx http://website/SecondService.asmx`  is the list of webservices that you need to call
- `Pause` means that you want window's shel to remain open to read the feedback of the operations.

---

NOTE
1) **All instructions must be in one line** (don't press enter); `Pause` in the second line.
2) If `/o:C:\code\MyProxy.cs` will be part of your solution (i think so) and you use *source control*, **the file must be checked out** to be overwritten by wsdl.exe